# How can I store 1 000 000 000 items in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, int

I'm doing an exercise requested by my teacher. The work needs to evaluate a large amount of values (up to 1 000 000 000 to be precise) and the program is giving error as I try to add values in the `PosFez` array.

I think I have to use `malloc` but I've learned this stuff some time ago and I do not remember how to do it. I also think that trying to evaluate the values directly would work but the only way I could think I needed to save the data too

```
#include <stdio.h>

int n,m,q;

int main(){
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);

    int PosFez[m];

    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        scanf("%d",&PosFez[i]);
    }

    int Postos[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){ 
        Postos[i] = 0;
    }


    scanf("%d",&q);

    int p[q];

    for(int i = 0; i<q;i++){
        scanf("%d",&p[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < PosFez[i]; j++){
            Postos[j]++;
        }
    }   


    for(int i=0; i<q;i++){  
        printf("%d\n",Postos[PosFez[i]-1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: That will quite likely break the stack: use `malloc` to allocate it. And some compilers won't even do that: my MSVC only gives about 2Gb memory available to the whole program.

Comment: I don't realy remembre how to do it. If you could help me

Comment: Change the line `int PosFez[m];` to `int *PosFez = malloc(m * sizeof(int));`, and don't forget to do `free(PosFez);` when you're done with the array. For that matter, do the same with `Postos` and `p` if you expect `n` and `q` to be large as well.

Comment: @MikeHolt thanks, I will need the data for the entire program so I should do `free(PosFez);` before end right?

Comment: @GuilhermeSilva if you exit the program without explicitly free the memory it will be freed anyway with the rest of the memory used by it

Comment: @GuilhermeSilva Yes. Do the `free` any time *after* you're done using the array, but before the end of the program. Just make sure no part of your code will attempt to access the array after you've `free`'d it.

Comment: @MikeHolt Ok Thank you ;)

Comment: Given how much memory you would need to allocate, there’s a good chance the task doesn’t actually require that much memory.  Think again about what you actually need to do.

Comment: If you have that much data you might as well use files. Store your data in a file then access the file and put your output  in a different file. That way you'll use much less ram. I don't know what you are doing but if you don't need all the data at once then files maybe a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

> The work needs to evaluate a large amount of values (up to 1 000 000 000 to be precise) and the program is giving error as I try to add values in the PosFez array
>
> ```
>  int PosFez[m];
> ```

you cannot have an array of 1000 000 000 *int* in the stack, the stack size is limited (typically some Mbytes, see *ulimit* under Linux /Unix), allocate the array in the head using for instance *malloc*  for that

In case you are not sure to need a so large array you can allocate less, and each time needed to use *realloc* to increase its size

Answer (score 0):

First let's do a quick calculation:
Assuming an int takes 4 Byte (32bit) on your machine, you would need round about 3.7GB RAM just to store the data. So if you only have 4GB of Memory you will likely run out, due to the OS and other Programs already occupying a good part of it.

Second, as mentioned by other users, this amount of data will not fit in the stack. You have to allocate memory by using `malloc` for example. [This site](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_memory_management.htm) should help you learn how.

If you really have that many values, i guess the data is provided in some kind of file to you. Instead of loading everything into memory just parse the file and evaluate it step by step.
Otherwise you could always write the data into a file and then go from the there.